# Uninstall exe program in through cmd

Tags: c#, cmd, exe, windows-installer

I am writing an app to remove an old version of Qmuzik ERP software from a network and install the new version. I have used the Process methods in C# to execute the msi through a cmd command to install the new version. The command I use is:

```
msiexec /qn /i "MSI Path"
```

This works beautifully.

The reason I am doing this is because of the fact that there are more than one msi which has to be run in sequence. Using the process method I can watch the process and detect when it is done and execute the next msi in the sequence. All of this happens quietly on the users pc.

The problem is, before I can install the new version I have to uninstall the previous version. The old version was installed on to the machines using an exe setup file. I have tried converting the exe file to msi and using msiexec to uninstall through command line but it has no effect on the instances that has been installed with the exe and not the converted msi (which is the entire network)

Is there any Command that I can use in cmd to uninstall these instances that has been installed using the exe?

Comment: use revo uninstaller, not for its uninstallation features, but for its main view, that shows the registered uninstall string of your application

Comment: @SteveB, I downloaded and installed revo uninstaller. I got the uninstall string in the registry, the value is "C:\PROGRA~2\Qmuzik32\UNWISE.EXE C:\PROGRA~2\Qmuzik32\INSTALL.LOG" Ami I correct in saying I need to execute the UNWISE.EXE file through command line to uninstall? Keep in mind, this has to be done quietly (ie no interaction required from the user)

Comment: it's a starting point. Every setup engine can have its own uninstall string. You have to find the correct one, if you are lucky enough for it to exists (try /quiet, /passive, etc. until you find the correct one)

Comment: @Steve B If you add your comments above to an answer I will happily accept it. Thanks for your help. I got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use revo uninstaller, not for its uninstallation features, but for its main view, that shows the registered uninstall string of your application.

But it's only a starting point. Every setup engine can have its own uninstall string. You have to find the correct one, if you are lucky enough for it to exists (try /quiet, /passive, etc. until you find the correct one).

Comment: Not really an answer. Just guidance.

Answer (score 4):

When you install a program in Windows a registry key for its uninstallation is created holding several values, among them is the **UninstallString** value which is the command line the **Add or remove programs** uses when you click **Remove**.

The parent key is:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

And these **UninstallStrings** usually have the following format:

> MsiExec.exe /I{0826F9E4-787E-481D-83E0-BC6A57B056D5}

In order to acomplish what you are trying to do you will have to create a [RegistryKey object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx), read the **UninstallString** value for the application you want to remove and run the command line.

More info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314481).

Comment: +1, nice answer, some of them even have a `QuietUninstallString` :) http://i.imgur.com/AUkm3.png

Comment: Thomas, thanks for this. It helped me. To be fair I have to accept Thomas B's answer as he was the first one to give the answer (even though it was in a comment :-D). If he does not change his comment to an answer I will gladly accept yours. Giving you a one up though. I did not have to create a registry key object as it was possible to execute the uninstall string through command pramt with a few parameters to uninstall the app quietly. Thanks a mil once again! J

Comment: Sorry, I meant @Steve B's answer/comment

Comment: Don't worry about that Joachim, I'm just glad to know my answer was helpful to you :)

Answer (score -3):

Go to the FIle Path, looks for a .exe which you need to uninstall. In command prompt open the path of .exe located and execute "xxxx.exe --uninstall".